# Goto and Compile to C

Tags: compile

When I use `Goto` inside compile and use `CompilationTarget->"C"` I get error message:

```
fun = Compile[{},
      Goto["here"];
      Label["here"];
      , CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

or

```
fun2 = Compile[{{myt, _Real}, {i, _Integer}},
      Module[{t = myt},
       Do[If[j >= i, Goto["one"], Goto["two"]];
        Label["one"];
        t = j;
        Break[];
        Label["two"];, {j, 1, 10}];
       t
       ], CompilationTarget -> "C"

      ]
```

> > SymbolicC`ToCCodeString::unk: An unknown element, CCodeGenerator`Private`buildLine[10,CCodeGenerator`Private`objData$1791,CompiledFunctionTools`Private`getInstruction[10,{0,one}]], was found when generating code >>
> >
> > CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\d985623-6852\Working-number-6852-6272-1\compiledFunction0.c(104) : error C2065: 'CUnknownElement' : undeclared identifier >>

Without compiling to `C` it works well.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't support goto.  It should always be possible to rephrase a program without goto though.

Comment: here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

it says it is compilable. How can I for example rephrase `fun2` without `Goto`?

Comment: worth reiterating the issue is specific to the `CompilationTarget->"C"` option.  Works fine for other (or no) target specified. For your example you can just put the code blocks inside the `If`.

Comment: @george2079 It works when I put the code block inside `If`. Thank you.

Comment: @yashar Yes, it was clear from your question that it's compilable to byte code.  I meant to say that that doesn't necessarily mean that it's compilable to C.  You could ask Wolfram support about it though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost 3 years later.. The problem lies in the `Label` instruction. What happens when you have code that contains labels and gotos is that the `Goto` instructions are successfully converted to valid jump op-codes. The labels, however, are just, well, labels. They don't even have a meaning, because jumps in compiled code are converted to jumps to a *line number*. Therefore, they are turned into *no-ops*. this can be seen in this example:

```
fun = Compile[{{a, _Real, 0}},
  Module[{x = 1., xp = 0., begin, end},
   Label[begin];
   If[Abs[xp - x] < 10^-8, Goto[end]];
   xp = x;
   x = (x + a/x)/2;
   Goto[begin];
   Label[end];
   x]
  ]
```

Look at `fun // InputForm` and you will find `{0, begin}` which means op-code 0 for "nothing". When a C function is to be constructed from this compiled function, every op-code is converted into its C form. Like this:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompiledFunctionTools`Private`getInstruction[0, {16, 0, 1}]

(* Instruction[Times, Register[Real, 1], {Register[Real, 0]}] *)
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be an oversight that exactly this is not implemented for the noop code. Since it cannot be turned into a valid instruction, the C-compiler will never get a valid instruction list. Look at the error

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can we fix this? Surely. The question is what is the next best instruction for a noop instruction? Well, jump to the next line sounds reasonable.

To understand why this works you have to know that jumps to *labels* are turned into jumps to *line numbers*. So we don't really need the labels at all at this stage anymore.

```
Unprotect[CompiledFunctionTools`Private`getInstruction];
CompiledFunctionTools`Private`getInstruction[line_, {0, _}] := 
 CompiledFunctionTools`Private`getInstruction[line, {3, 1}]
```

Instruction `{3,1}` is a jump (3) to the line: current line + 1.

```
fun = Compile[{{a, _Real, 0}},
  Module[{x = 1., xp = 0., begin, end},
   Label[begin];
   If[Abs[xp - x] < 10^-8, Goto[end]];
   xp = x;
   x = (x + a/x)/2;
   Goto[begin];
   Label[end];
   x], CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]

fun[2]
(* 1.41421 *)
```